# How to map each line to get multiline output rdd

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

Given an input rdd or form

```
1: 6 7
2: 5
```

How can i get another rdd of form

```
1 6
1 7
2 5
```

and so on..

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what kind of data structure the input is, and how you're trying to process it. For example, is it a dictionary (what are the keys and values)? or is it a text file? or is it a string? or...

Comment: It is actually an RDD. But the logic for a dictionary can hold good for RDD as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flatMap throws error -unicode item does not have attribute flatMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540559/flatmap-throws-error-unicode-item-does-not-have-attribute-flatmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume your initial input is in a text file then you can call two map functions like this:

```
data = sc.textFile("textfile_location")
data = data.map(lambda line: (line.split(":")[0], line.split(":")[1].split()))
data = data.flatMap(lambda key, values: [(key, value) for value in values])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super clear on how RDDs work, but you say that it can be turned into a `dict`. So let's say, you have the following dict:

```
d = {1: [6, 7], 2: [5]}
```

And let's say you want to write that information into a file:

```
1 6
1 7
2 5
```

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for k in sorted(d):
        for v in d[k]:
            outfile.write("{}\t{}\n".format(k, v))
```

Comment: @mhn: Can what be done using lambda expressions? Which component of my code do you want to replace with a lambda?