# flatMap throws error -unicode item does not have attribute flatMap

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Given an input rdd or form

```
1: 6 7
2: 5
```

How can i get another rdd of form

```
1 6
1 7
2 5
```

and so on..

fails with message unicode item does not have attribute flatMap

```
def get_str(x,y):
    ..code to flatmap 
    return op
text = sc.textFile(inputs)
res = text.map(lambda l:l.split(":")).map(lambda (x,y):get_str(x,y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really into Python, but it looks like you're trying to use `flatMap` *inside* your `map`, but rather you need to replace your `map` with `flatMap`. In Scala, I would do:

```scala
val text = sc.textFile(inputs)
val res = text.map(l => l.split("[\\s:]+"))
              .flatMap(list => list.drop(1).map(i => (list(0), i)))
```

Note that I split on both `" "` and `":"` to get a list of values.

The same thing in Python:

```py
def to_seq(s):
    k, vs = s.split(":")
    for v in vs.split():
        yield k, v

text = sc.parallelize(["1: 6 7", "2: 5"])
res = text.flatMap(to_seq)
res.take(3)

## [('1', '6'), ('1', '7'), ('2', '5')]
```